# Get all data where pivot id (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Is there the best way/the simplest way to get all data where pivot?
I tried this `$article = Article::with('category')->wherePivot('category_id', $category)->get();` but i got error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `articles` where `pivot` = category_id)
```

The relation is many to many

> Article
>
> - id
> - content

```
public function category(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'articles_has_categories', 'article_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

> Articles_Has_Categories
>
> - id
> - article_id
> - category_id

```
public function article ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Article::class,'article_id');
    }

    public function category ()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id');
    }
```

> Category
>
> - id
> - name

```
public function article(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class, 'articles_has_categories', 'category_id', 'article_id');
    }
```

Comment: what about your model relationship? can you post your models code as well? what is `$category`?

Comment: i have update my question @Dev

Comment: Hey what is `$category`?

Comment: category_id that i send from url @Dev

Comment: I SOLVE MY PROBLEM TRYING WITH `whereHas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
    $article = Article::with(['category' => function($query) use ($category) {
            $query->where('category_id', $category);
        }
    ])->get();
```

Comment: Are you passing the right category ID? T be sure you are passing the correct ID, try to hard code the categoryID. in where clause and see the result `$query->where('category_id', 1)`. Please make sure there is an article with the category you are passing.

Comment: Yes i'm. There is empty data for relation

Comment: I believe the problem is with $catedory How are you passing the $category ID from view to the controller. Please share with same code.

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/articlesjson?category=1`. i tried passing it with url so i didnt do the mistake with the category_id

Answer (score 0):

```
$article = Article::with(['category' => function($query) use ($category) {
        $query->whereHas('category_id', $category);
    }
])->get();
```

If you use `$category` as array the use `$query->whereHas('category_id', $category);` or else if you use `$category` is a single id `$query->where('category_id', $category);`

Comment: @Ray try my one and see what's your output.